# change the default distance in between the parallel axis in highchart

Tags: javascript, web, highcharts

I am using the high-chart to draw the graph.

**Code**

[Complete code is non JS_Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/plotbordercolor/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

**Graph:**
[image]

**Problem:**
Problem is that i want to change the distance in between all parallel lines from 50 to 10 as you can see in the image. You can see the code on [js_fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/plotbordercolor/). I have been search for the solution more than 5 hours. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Luckily:
I spend alot of hours but luckily when i post the question on stackoverflow. After 5min of this post i found the solution.

These two properties help me to find my solution.

```
tickPositions
tickPositioner
```

[Js_Fiddle Solution:](http://jsfiddle.net/0xb2c8e5/)